# Unable to set state even when checking for mount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to set a state value using the `useState` method `setCurrentBreakpoint` so that I can use it in a if statement.

But I end up with following error.

> index.js:1 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted
> component.  This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your
> application.  To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks
> in the componentWillUnmount method. in Media (at src/index.tsx:180)

It seems to be more an issue with the library as stated here.

> https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-media/issues/139

I need this value to use it in the if statement shown below.

Anyway to get around this? Checking for mount doesn't matter.

Tried with `useRef` just in case and same outcome.

Pls advice. Maybe a workaround without using state?

Checked the lib and seems quite stale thus not much use in trying to make any change to the lib.

I tried with the latest v2 of this `react-media` lib and same outcome.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import Media from "react-media";

const [isMounted, setIsMounted] = React.useState(false);
const [currentBreakpoint, setCurrentBreakpoint] = React.useState("sm");

React.useEffect(() => {
  setIsMounted(true);
  return () => {
    console.log(`unmount. This never prints so actually there is no dismount`);
    setIsMounted(false);
  };
}, []);

if ("some logic") {
  return externalFunc(currentBreakpoint);
  // return this instead
  // I need to store currentBreakpoint so that I can use it in this if statement
}

return (
    <Media
      queries={{
        sm: "(max-width: 767px)",
        md: "(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px)",
        lg: "(min-width: 1024px)"
      }}
    >
      {(result: MediaResult) => {
        if (currentBreakpoint !== currentResult.current) {
          setCurrentBreakpoint(currentResult.current); {/* this line is causing the error. */}
        }
        return children(currentResult);
      }}
    </Media>
  );
```

Comment: How about remove all of your `states/useState`, `useEffect`, and `if ("some logic")` 
 function. And do everything you need inside the Media component (the children of `<Media>`) like what they do here in their [readme](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-media/blob/master/README.md?plain=1#L94-L101)